# hcitool scan returns different name results for the same mac address

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, hci

while using `hcitool scan --info --oui --class` to get classic bluetooth devices, I am receiving devices names different every time for the same device. at times the device name are not in human readable format.
why is this happening and how to resolve this issue?

## 1

```
hcitool -i hci0 scan --oui --info --class
Scanning ...

BD Address: 5C:49:7D:6E:E3:EF [mode 1, clkoffset 0x272a]
Device name:    0{\��
Device class:   Audio/Video, Video Display and Loudspeaker (0x08043c)
```

## 2

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 scan --oui --info --class
Scanning ...

BD Address: 5C:49:7D:6E:E3:EF [mode 1, clkoffset 0x272a]
Device name:    Pc0�
Device class:   Audio/Video, Video Display and Loudspeaker (0x08043c)
```

## 3

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 scan --oui --info --class
Scanning ...

BD Address: 5C:49:7D:6E:E3:EF [mode 1, clkoffset 0x272c]
Device name:    [TV] Samsung 6 Series (55)
Device class:   Audio/Video, Video Display and Loudspeaker (0x08043c)
```